# Post getting posted as private and not public on Facebook

Tags: facebook

We are facing issue while posting the Article links on our created page.

1. We have one functionality implemented in which We posts Article links on our Facebook page by using our back-end system.
2. When any user visits our Facebook Page and clicks on these Article links (which is shared from our back-end) user will be redirected to our own Android App.(in particular Article section present in our own App)
3. When we are testing this functionality, we are facing below challenge.
4. Currently when we try to publish any Article link, it is getting posted on timeline of the page as private not public. So everyone is not able to see this Article link.
5. Also I am being Admin, can’t find rights to make my posts Public on timeline.
6. This page is not created using my own Facebook account but by using one of my friends. I was made Admin after creating page. So in this case posts are not made as public on timeline. Above is the overall description for this issue. Please Note : We are using my Facebook account details in our back-end system to posts Article links.
7. Other side for this is if I create a page using my own account and then using my credentials at back-end and then publish Article links then All posts are getting posted as public so my problem gets resolved.
8. but this is not happening for the page I want.

   Can anyone please help?

Comment: _“it is getting posted on timeline of the page as private not public”_ – so you are not making a post as the page, but as a user (so that it will show up on the left under “posts by others”)? Because posts made _as_ a page do not have a public/private privacy setting to begin with.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for your help. Can you let me know how can I make as public on the page. Or only the page owner can do it?

Comment: It's not clear if you're actually posting AS the page, or AS a user and TO the page - are you using a user access token or page access token to make the call to `/<PAGE ID>/feed` ?